# "app-root" not loading in client side angular simple project

Tags: angular, angular-routing

i'm new in angular, My project has a problem on the client side, so I made a simple angular project to see where  is the problem.
i create new project in angular, by `ng new ejt` and in index.html write this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ejt</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <div>index file</div>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

and in app.component.html write this:

```
<body><div>app-componnent</div></body>
```

by `ng serve --open` display this page :

[image]

so build it by:

```
 ng build --base-href='/ejt/'
```

Then I copied the `ejt` folder to the server on the local network.
after that  on the iis setting adding application setting ,set Alias as `ejt` and physical path to `ejt` folder that copying on the server,
index.html file in published folder is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ejt</title>
  <base href="/ejt/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c.css"></head>
<body>
  <div>index file</div>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.c6237a260db867c3cc5b.js" defer></script>
<script src="polyfills.afb48eddb7f7a81387e2.js" defer></script>
<script src="main.859c2954c4de5ec61543.js" defer></script>

</body></html>
```

and added web.config by this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/ejt/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The problem is that the index page is displayed on the server like this:

[image]

This is true on server side and the client side should be displayed in the same way but in client side not load `<app-root></app-root>`  section in published index.html file and display this :

[image]

Please help, I have not been able to solve the problem for a week

Comment: Try changing the rewrite to `<action type="Rewrite" url="/ejt/index.html" />`

Comment: changing the rewrite to <action type="Rewrite" url="/ejt/index.html" /> not work

Comment: check your dev tools, if the scripts of your app are loaded

Comment: I'm new. Help me more. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you work alone? Do you have a senior dev in your team? You have to be mentored on this, this is not something I can help you with in one paragraph.

Comment: Yes, I am alone and no one is helping me

Comment: Read this: https://angular.io/guide/deployment and this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools

Comment: in developer console i recive this errors:
SyntaxError: missing = in const declaration            polyfills.afb48eddb7f7a81387e2.js:1:12229
SyntaxError: missing = in const declaration            main.859c2954c4de5ec61543.js:1:19743

Comment: Now look at the actual response from the network requests for these files, see that you're getting an html file instead of the script. this means your rewrite rules are wrong

Comment: Do you mean that in the file web.config I wrote the URL incorrectly?

Comment: Either that, or the file layout on disk doesn't agree with the rule.